# Implementing a Time class in c++

Tags: c++, beginner, object-oriented

> Design a class TIME which stores hour, minute and second. The class
>   should have
>
> the methods to support the following:
>
> 1. User may give the time value in 24-hour format.
> 2. User may give the time value in AM/PM format
> 3. Display the time in 24-hour format.
> 4. Display the time in AM/PM format.
> 5. User may like to add minute with a time value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Time {
    public:
        Time(int h = 0, int m = 0, int s = 0, const std::string &am_or_pm = "");
        void print_time24();
        void print_time12();
        void add_min();
    private:
        int hr;
        int min;
        int sec;
};

Time::Time(int h, int m, int s, const std::string &am_or_pm):
    hr(h), min(m), sec(s)
{
    if (am_or_pm == "AM" && hr == 12)
        hr = 0;
    if (am_or_pm == "PM" && hr != 12)
        hr += 12;
}

void Time::print_time24()
{
    std::cout << hr << ':' << min << ':' << sec;
}

void Time::print_time12()
{
    if (hr == 0 || hr == 12)
        std::cout << "12";
    else
        std::cout << hr % 12;
    std::cout << ':' << min << ':' << sec;

    if (hr / 12 == 0)
        std::cout << " AM";
    else
        std::cout << " PM";
}

void Time::add_min()
{
    if (min == 59)
        hr = (hr + 1) % 24;

    min = (min + 1) % 60;
}

// To test the class
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "Choose option(1. 12 hr format 2. 24 hr format): ";
    int op;
    cin >> op;
    cout << "Enter the time: ";
    int hr, min, sec;
    cin >> hr >> min >> sec;
    string am_or_pm;
    if (op == 1)
        cin >> am_or_pm;
    Time t(hr, min, sec, am_or_pm);
    t.print_time12();
    cout << '\n';
    t.print_time24();
    cout << '\n';

    cout << "Adding a minute,\n";
    t.add_min();
    t.print_time12();
    cout << '\n';
    t.print_time24();
    cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The code works but can it be made better? Also what will be the correct way to handle invalid arguments in the constructor?

Comment: I would have expected `add_min` to take the number of minutes to add which don't need to be below 60.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see some things that may help you improve your program.

### Use `const` where practical

The `print_time24()` and `print_time12()` functions only print and do not modify the underlying `Time` object, so they should both be declared `const`:

```
void print_time24() const;
void print_time12() const;
```

### Make printing prettier

The current `print_time24()` routine does not emit nice looking time.  If the time is 12:06:07, the program emits `12:6:7` which is not quite right.  Instead, you have to format the data so that minutes and seconds are both two digits.  I show how in the next comment.

### Create a stream inserter

Right now the code is only capable of printing to `std::cout` and not a `std::stringstream` or `std::ofstream`.  This can be fixed by one of two ways.  Either you can add a `std::ostream&` parameter to each of the print routines or you can create a `friend` inserter like this:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Time& t) {
    auto oldfill = out.fill('0');
    return out << t.hr 
        << ':' << std::setw(2) << t.min 
        << ':' << std::setw(2) << t.sec << std::setfill(oldfill);
}
```

You will also have to `#include <iomanip>`.  Now it can be used like so:

```
cout << t << '\n';
```

### Think of the user

While the `add_min()` routine does indeed add exactly 1 minute, I would instead have expected that one would be able to add an arbitrary number of minutes instead, as with `add_min(int minutes)`.

Also, it seems likely that a user would have a preference for either AM/PM or 24-hour time.  I'd suggest making that preference either a boolean data member of the class or perhaps a static data member for all instances of the class.

### Consider signed vs. unsigned

Would a time of `-3:-80:-155` be something you would recognize as a time?  Probably not, but unfortunately your `Time` object has no problem with that. Both the constructor arguments and the `private` data members should be `unsigned` rather than `int`.  If you want to save some space, you could even declare the private data members as `unsigned char`.

### Use braces

Lines like this:

```
if (am_or_pm == "AM" && hr == 12)
    hr = 0;
```

while technically accurate are a potential error waiting to happen.  The problem is that if someone adds a line, perhaps for troubleshooting or diagnostics, the `if` statement will break unless braces are added.  You can both make your code more clear and prevent this kind of future error by using braces.

### Handle out-of-range constructor arguments

There are two choices for how to handle invalid constructor arguments.  Either you can ignore them and silently substitute a default or `throw` an error.  I'd recommend the latter approach.  At the bottom of your constructor, add these three lines:

```
if (hr > 24 || min > 59 || sec > 59) {
    throw(std::domain_error("Time value out of range"));
}
```

You will also have to `#include <stdexcept>`.

### Use helper functions to make code simpler

The code to print the time could be much simpler if you use helper functions.  I'd suggest these member functions:

```
    bool is_pm() const {
        return hr >= 12;
    }
private:
    unsigned get_hour(bool am_pm) const {
        if (!am_pm)
            return hr;
        if (is_pm())
            return hr-12;
        if (hr == 0)
            return 12;
        return hr;
    }
    const char *get_suffix(bool am_pm) const {
        if (!am_pm)
            return "";
        if (is_pm())
            return " PM";
        return " AM";
    }
```

Now the two separate print routines can be refactored as one member function taking a `bool` to tell whether to print 24-hour or AM/PM time:

```
std::ostream& print(std::ostream &out, bool am_pm) const
{
    auto oldfill = out.fill('0');
    return out << get_hour(am_pm)
        << ':' << std::setw(2) << min 
        << ':' << std::setw(2) << sec 
        << get_suffix(am_pm)
        << std::setfill(oldfill);
}
```

This, in turn can be used by the `friend` inserter I mentioned above:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Time& t) {
    return t.print(out, false);
}
```

### Simplify the `add_min()` code

The code does more mathematics than it needs to.  Now that the constructor throws an error if it's malformed, we know that the stored values are always valid.  This means that the `add_min()` code can be simplified:

```
void Time::add_min()
{
    if (++min > 60) {
        hr = (hr + 1) % 24;
        min = 0;
    }
}
```

### Eliminate `return 0` at the end of main

When a C++ program reaches the end of `main` the compiler will automatically generate code to return 0, so there is no reason to put `return 0;` explicitly at the end of `main`.

Comment: For the functions which do not change the invoking object, do we need the const keyword also in the definition, or just in the function declaration?

Comment: The `const` keyword needs to be both in the declaration and in the definition.

Comment: Is calling that operator an inserter common? I haven't heard that before, but I prefer it to other names I've heard.

Comment: @Dannnno: Yes, it's quite commonly called a inserter (or when being more specific, "stream inserter").

Comment: Yes, `<<` is commonly called an inserter and `>>` is commonly called an extractor.  See [Stroustrup's glossary page](http://www.stroustrup.com/glossary.html).